# AudioQueue doesn't produce any sound. What the problem can be?

Tags: c++, macos, core-audio, audiotoolbox

I've written a small c++ app for testing AudioToolbox Queue. I am filling the buffer with some random data just to check it works.

```
static void HandleOutputBuffer(void* inUserData, AudioQueueRef queue, AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer) {
    memset(inBuffer->mAudioData, rand() % 256, inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize);
    throwExceptionIfError(AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(queue, inBuffer, 0, NULL));
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    AudioQueueRef queue;
    AudioStreamBasicDescription format = {0};
    format.mBytesPerFrame = 4;
    format.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    format.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
    format.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    format.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    format.mBytesPerPacket = format.mBytesPerFrame;
    format.mSampleRate = 44100;
    format.mReserved = 0;
    format.mFormatFlags =  kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger |
            kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian |
            kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;
    throwExceptionIfError(AudioQueueNewOutput(&format, HandleOutputBuffer, NULL,
            NULL, // Use internal thread
            kCFRunLoopDefaultMode,
            0, // Reserved, must be 0
            &queue));

    AudioQueueBufferRef buffer;
    throwExceptionIfError(AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(queue, 1024, &buffer));
    buffer->mAudioDataByteSize = 1024;
    throwExceptionIfError(AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(queue, buffer, 0, NULL));
    throwExceptionIfError(AudioQueueStart(queue, NULL));

    @autoreleasepool {
        // Setup code that might create autoreleased objects goes here.
    }
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}
```

HandleOutputBuffer is called continuously, I checked. However I can't hear any sound. What the problem can be?

Comment: Did you try the solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384152/audioqueue-does-not-output-any-sound?rq=1 ?

Comment: Yeah. it helps. Thanks. I haven't found this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem your code has is that it is not enqueueing enough buffers. `AudioQueues` seem to like having at least two:

```
AudioQueueBufferRef buffer;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    throwExceptionIfError(AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(queue, 1024, &buffer));
    buffer->mAudioDataByteSize = 1024;
    throwExceptionIfError(AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(queue, buffer, 0, NULL));
}
```